# Can't find date in an array of dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

Having problems with this:

```js
var arr = new Array();
var d = new Date("2018-05-23");

arr.push(new Date("2017-10-01"))
arr.push(new Date("2018-05-23"))
arr.push(new Date("2018-12-31"))
var y = arr.includes(d);
console.log("Y: ", y);
var y = arr.indexOf(d);
console.log("Y: ", y);
/* Returns false and -1 */
```

Comment: Objects are only ever equal if they're the same object. Date objects don't compare as equal whether they represent the same date or not. You would have to `reduce` the array or use `find`/[`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a custom callback.

Comment: this is because the elapsed ms between the 2 created dates ("2018-05-23")

Comment: @Sergi No, that is not the reason. `new Date(0) == new Date(0)` is also `false`.

Comment: If you check their times (ms) are not the same